# Detect numbers which are close and has same index value in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, each

I've a complicated timeline which has lots of tags with different positions and if dates are close tags overlaps. Need to separate tags which overlaps.

I have `rowIndex` value which indicates aligned tags in rows:

---tag------tag----tag-------- (row)

--------tag--tag---tag---tag- (row)

I have `tagIndex` value which i can separate them from each other in current row.

And last value is `left`. This value defines position of the current tag.

Array is like this:

```
var tagsPosiArr = [
    {left: "8%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 0},
    {left: "40%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 1},
    {left: "92%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 2},
    {left: "10%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 0},//here
    {left: "11%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 1},//here
    {left: "11%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 2},//here
    {left: "12%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 3},//here
    {left: "40%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 4},
    {left: "8%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 0},
    {left: "10%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 1},//here
    {left: "92%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 2}//here
];

$.each(tagsPosiArr,function (index) {
    console.log(this);
    //console.log(this.rowIndex);
    //Function should compare all of `left` values in `rowIndex` and return values which are close (in range of 16).
    // vales are highlated with "// here" text
});
```

I'm trying to separate tags which has close `left` value in same row.  Function should compare all of `left` values in `rowIndex` and return values which are close (in range of 16).

My current limit is `16%`, **i need to detect these tags**:

- tagA, left = 0%
- tagB, left = 15%

These are okey:

- tagA, left = 0%
- tagB, left = 30%
- tagC, left = 80%

[**Here is jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcf2h562/12/), i'm stucked, any ideas will be appreciated.

Note: I can not show whole work, i hope this will enough.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Your jsFiddle nor your question doesn't show any effort to resolve it

Comment: @A.Wolff i can not detect previous, current and next values to measure with, need to detect 16% range. I can get values but stucked at the formula /:

Comment: Is requirement to filter items within `tagsPosiArr` which have `left` property value less than or equal to `16%` ? Not certain about `0%, 30%, 80%` being "okey" too ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 it should compare all of left values in rowIndex and return values which are close (in range of 16)

Comment: `left:92%, rowIndex:17` marked "here" at edited post / jsfiddle , though appear greater than "16" range ? Also , `{left: "8%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 0}` _not_ marked "here" , though range appear within "16" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tagsPosiArr.sort(function (lhs, rhs) {
    return lhs.rowIndex > rhs.rowIndex ? 1 : lhs.rowIndex < rhs.rowIndex ? -1 : parseInt(lhs.left) > parseInt(rhs.left) ? 1 : parseInt(lhs.left) < parseInt(rhs.left) ? -1 : 0;
});

var min = 16;

var prev;
var match = 0;

var overlapping = [];
var overlappingId = 0;
$.each(tagsPosiArr, function (index) {

    if (prev != undefined && this.rowIndex == prev.rowIndex && parseInt(this.left) - parseInt(prev.left) < min) {
        if(match === 0){
            overlapping[overlappingId] = [prev];
        }
        overlapping[overlappingId].push(this);
        ++match;        
    } else{
        if(match != 0){
            match = 0;
            ++overlappingId;
        }
    }
    prev = this;
});

console.log(overlapping);

//=>
// [
//   [
//     {left: "10%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 0},
//     {left: "11%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 1},
//     {left: "11%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 2},
//     {left: "12%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 3}
//   ],
//   [
//     {left: "8%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 0},
//     {left: "10%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 1}
//   ]
// ]
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xcf2h562/14/

Comment: This seems perfect, this seems really close but still incomplete, http://jsfiddle.net/xcf2h562/10/ look at the fiddle i've prepared. It should be return 4 values at rowIndex 10, but it returns 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep)

```
    var tagsPosiArr = [
        {left: "8%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 0},
        {left: "40%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 1},
        {left: "92%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 2},
        {left: "10%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 0},
        {left: "40%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 1},
        {left: "8%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 0},
        {left: "10%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 1},
        {left: "92%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 2}
    ];

    var filtered = $.grep(tagsPosiArr,function (value, index) {
        return (parseInt(value.left) <= 16)
    });
    // `filtered` : items within `tagsPosiArr` having `left` value
    // less than or equal to `16%`
    console.log(filtered);
```

```js
    var tagsPosiArr = [
        {left: "8%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 0},
        {left: "40%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 1},
        {left: "92%", rowIndex: 0, tagIndex: 2},
        {left: "10%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 0},
        {left: "40%", rowIndex: 10, tagIndex: 1},
        {left: "8%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 0},
        {left: "10%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 1},
        {left: "92%", rowIndex: 17, tagIndex: 2}
    ];
    
    var filtered = $.grep(tagsPosiArr,function (value, index) {
        return (parseInt(value.left) <= 16)
    });
    // `filtered` : items within `tagsPosiArr` having `left` value
    // less than or equal to `16%`
    console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it seems perfect but it returns wrong /: It returns 8% and 10% but if you look at their rowIndex you will see no close value to them. But rowIndex 17 values return true.

Comment: if you inspect this example, http://jsfiddle.net/xcf2h562/11/ you will see its returning rowIndex 0 and there is no targeted value in that row /: But you way is really fantastic also, i hope you will solve this, thank very much again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efford +1